# Sublime Text: I want to change outlined highlighting

Tags: user-interface, sublimetext3, highlight

I want to change the outlined highlighting in Sublime Text 3. It doesn't look appealing to me and is the only problem I have with ST3. Is there any way I can change it?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What is shown in your screenshot? Are those selections? Find/Replace highlighting? Highlighting from another plugin? Here is [**an example**](http://i.imgur.com/AdnrU2Z.png) from my personal color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different [**Color Scheme**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme).

---

If you are set on using your current `color scheme`, you can modify ( *or add* ) the following properties to your active `.tmTheme` file.

Set your preferred color values in between the `string` tags by using `#RRGGBB` format.

---

```
<!-- Selection -->

    <key>selection</key>
    <string>#1D416B</string>

    <key>selectionForeground</key>
    <string>#bbccff</string>

    <key>selectionBorder</key>
    <string>#4D71FF</string>

<!-- Inactive Selection -->

    <key>inactiveSelection</key>
    <string>#1D416B</string>

    <key>inactiveSelectionForeground</key>
    <string>#bbccff</string>

<!-- Search Results -->

    <key>findHighlight</key>
    <string>#0BD0AC</string>

    <key>findHighlightForeground</key>
    <string>#000000</string>
```